# Is it possible to use 2 different authorization schemes inside the same MVC Controller class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am currently working with a legacy .NET Framework application that has a webclient (MVC) and a mobile client. I have successfully configured my project to use bearer tokens for my webapi controllers and session cookies for my mvc controller using the following in my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
////Tells APIs to ignore the Default Cookie Type Authentication
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(newHostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

However, within my MVC contrtollers I have some methods that return an IActionResult() and some that return a JSonResult. Is it possible to define an attribute/authshcema on a per basis controller method that would allow my JsonResult controller methods to use bearer tokens instead of cookies sessions, despite not being inside a webapi controller?? This would allow me to call these controller methods from my mobile client and save me a lot of time having to refactor these methods into separate controllers.

Example:

```
//MVC Controller (Not Web API)
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
  //Should use cookie session
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      return View();
  }

  //Should use bearer tokens
  [HttpGet]
  public JsonResult GetPrograms()
  {
      var menu = _menuService.GetMenu();
      return new JsonResult
      {
          Data = menu,
          JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. It seemed that you are talking about ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET WebAPI and ASP.NET Core but you are not clear where your problem is. I have 0 idea why you mention your "startup" (ASP.NET Core term) and then post ASP.NET Web API code. Please [edit] your question and clarify it

Comment: You are correct that the word startup probably confused so I have removed it as this has nothing to do with Core. Otherwise I am in fact talking about both MVC and WebAPI as the same solution can contain both (using different auth methods), my question is in regards to consolidating the two, I believe it is quite clear.

Comment: IdentityServer4 requires ASP.NET Core, so why did you add that tag? Your question is still completely unclear, we cannot read your mind

Comment: Tokens are issued from IdS4 but validated using IdS3. Changed